# moving bucket data from regional to multiregional in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

currently  have the buckets created in multi-regional  i want change that to regional, I created a new regional bucket so how to move objects in the bucket  from multi-regional to regional

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.Open the Transfer page in the [Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets).

2.click Create transfer job.

3.select source as your multi regional bucket.

4.select destination as your regional bucket.

5.if you want to delete source bucket select delete objects from source once they are transferred.

6.click create.

This process may take some time; however, after you click Create, you can navigate away from the Google Cloud Console.

To view the transfer's progress: Open the Transfer page in the Google Cloud Console.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a one time copy you can use the gsutil command-line tool

```
gsutil -m cp -r gs://source-bucket gs://destination-bucket
```

> -m is used for parallel multi-threaded/multi-processing copy

> -r option to copy an entire directory tree